# Adding objects to an array using Swift without duplication

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am still getting familiar with Swift, and I am having troubles with adding objects to an array at this moment. 
Also the array shouldn't have duplicates.

**What I have so far -**

A function that is called when user does a button click on a prototype cell. 
**I am trying to achieve** -

1. Select button (and indicate with a checkmark that he selected/deselected the item)
2. For each selected item, I have two values - bool status `isActive` and the selected item's `subscriptionID`
3. When user selects the item, I need to add this selection as an object and further append this to an array.
4. For that, I have `subscriptionUpdateData: NSDictionary` and my new empty array `subscriptionsArray: [NSDictionary] = []`

**Full Function**

```
 func subscriptionCell(cell: SubscriptionCell, didToggleSubscription subscription: Subscriptions) {

        var subscriptionsArray: [NSDictionary] = []
        var subscriptionUpdateData: NSDictionary = ["subscriptionID": 0, "isActive": false]

        if let matchingSubscription = subscriptionInformation?.filter({ $0.subscriptionID == subscription.subscriptionID }).first {

            matchingSubscription.isActive = !(matchingSubscription.isActive!)

            let subscriptionStatus = matchingSubscription.isActive
            let subscriptionStatusForId = matchingSubscription.subscriptionID

            subscriptionUpdateData = ["subscriptionID": subscriptionStatusForId!, "isActive": subscriptionStatus!]
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
        subscriptionsArray.append(subscriptionUpdateData)
        print("\(subscriptionsArray)")

    }
```

**What is going on with above -**
I am able to select an item, form it as a dictionary, and add it to my array. :-) 
But whenever I select a different item in my list of items, it replaces the existing element in the array with the newly selected item. :-(

I am looking for something like below (without duplicates) which is an input to a REST endpoint -

```
    [{   "subscriptionID" : 1234, 
        "isActive" : true
    },
    {
        "subscriptionID" : 5678, 
        "isActive" : false
    },
    {
        "subscriptionID" : 3489, 
        "isActive" : true
    }]
```

Can someone look into where I am missing something? Or whether there is a better way I can do this?

Comment: Place your `var subscriptionsArray: [NSDictionary] = []` outside of `subscriptionCell` method may be  at instance level

Comment: the easiest way is to use predicates and filter your array to remove duplicates.

Comment: Why are you mixing Swift collection types and Cocoa collection types? Just use Swift collection types. In other words, don't use `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Add the `isActive` property to your data source model. An extra array is pretty cumbersome. And to get more familiar with Swift get rid of `NSDictionary` and use native Swift `Dictionary` or – still better – a custom class or struct.

Comment: Checkout the Set API to help you remove duplicate elements from a collection.

Answer (score 3):

You must declare **subscriptionsArray** as global variable, try this code:

```
    var subscriptionsArray: [NSDictionary] = []
    func subscriptionCell(cell: SubscriptionCell, didToggleSubscription subscription: Subscriptions) {
        var subscriptionUpdateData: NSDictionary = ["subscriptionID": 0, "isActive": false]

        if let matchingSubscription = subscriptionInformation?.filter({ $0.subscriptionID == subscription.subscriptionID }).first {

            matchingSubscription.isActive = !(matchingSubscription.isActive!)

            let subscriptionStatus = matchingSubscription.isActive
            let subscriptionStatusForId = matchingSubscription.subscriptionID

            subscriptionUpdateData = ["subscriptionID": subscriptionStatusForId!, "isActive": subscriptionStatus!]
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
        subscriptionsArray.append(subscriptionUpdateData)
        print("\(subscriptionsArray)")

    }
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. But how do I get rid of duplication?

Comment: To avoid duplication, you should be using a Set rather than an Array. If the order matters, then there is also an NSOrderedSet.

Comment: You can just use the NSDictionary: var subscriptions: NSDictionary = [Int: Bool] =[:] and add data by code: subscriptions[subscriptionStatusForId] = subscriptionStatus

Comment: This isn't a *global* variable; it's an *instance* variable (or, in Swift terms, a property).

Answer (score 1):

You can use swift dictionary to store those unique subscriptions by using their ids as keys:

```
id1: status1
id2: status2
...
```

Code sample:

```
var statusesDict = [Int: Bool?]()

func subscriptionToggled(subscription: Subscription) {
    if let matchingSubscription = subscriptionInformation?.filter({ $0.subscriptionID == subscription.subscriptionID }).first {
        let status = matchingSubscription.isActive
        let id = matchingSubscription.subscriptionID
        statusesDict[id] = status
    }
    //if you're using the same object from dataSource array, you dont need to look for it by filtering, just use the parameter object
}
```

Now, when you need to send the result to server just create an array from your dictionary:

```
func getSubscriptionsArray() -> [[String: Any]] {
    var result = [Dictionary<String, Any>]()
    for (id, status) in statusesDict.enumerated() {
        let subscriptionDict: [String: Any] = [
            "subscriptionID" : id,
            "isActive" : status
        ]
        result.append(subscriptionDict)
    }
    print("\(result)")
    return result
}
```

You should not send dictionary description as it is to server. First you should serialize it to JSON:

```
 let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: array, options: [])
 let string = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

For *pretty printed* json:

```
 let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: array, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
 let string = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

Comment: BTW, nobody uses the `Dictionary<Key, Value>` style of declaring dictionaries anymore. Just use `[Key : Value]`.

Comment: @alexburtnik: Got it! But in subscriptionDict, it should be status.0 for "subscriptionID" and status.1 for "isActive" since id is the index in statusesDict.enumerated()

Comment: But the end result is [["isActive": 0, "subscriptionID": 1241], ["isActive": 1, "subscriptionID": 1237]], But I am looking for array of objects like [{"isActive": 0, "subscriptionID": 1241}, {"isActive": 1, "subscriptionID": 1237}]

Comment: @LohithKorupolu You should serialize it to json first, don't send dictionary directly.

Comment: @alexburtnik: Simple logic missed! thanks a lot!! My brain should be defragmented once :-|